# Create custom cursor that changes dependant on where the mouse is along a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I looking for some help to create a series of custom cursor that changed dependant where the mouse is over a div and need some help.

In particular how to reference the number of the image in a slideshow being shown when H1 div is being hovered over.

See link below to my site
https://image-hover-effect-1.superhi.com/

and here's an example of what I am trying to achieve when hovering of the images on desktop

https://gt-walsheim.com/

Thanks!
S

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228826/how-to-change-cursor-based-on-mouse-position

Answer (score 0):

[This should help you on your way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

TLDR:

Create an image or find a cursor you like

Add a hover selector in CSS like this

```
.elm:hover{
    cursor:pointer
}
```